# ontouchstart event not working on Android default browser

Tags: svg, dom-events, touch-event, android-browser

I am firing an event using `ontouchstart`. It is working on other Android browsers like Firefox and Chrome (desktop too), but it is not functioning on the default Android browser.

Here is my code:

```
gauge.node.ontouchstart = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get("/varigate/zone/" + zoneId, function(zone) {
        $.get("/varigate/crop/" + zone['cropId'] + "/name", function(cropName) {
            var capitalized = cropName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + cropName.slice(1);
            deletePaddock();
            history.pushState(null, "Irrigation of Field " + paddockId, "irrigation/id=" + paddockId);
            switchToPage('gauge', irrigationPlan, paddockId, capitalized, zone['label'], currentFarm);
        });
    });
};
```